# jQuery attribute Selectors Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am have an issue with jQuery attribute selector, I can't understand why "Div 1" got the green background color in this example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[title],[style]').css('border', '5px solid red');
  $('[title][style]').css('background-color', 'green');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="div1Title">
  Div 1
</div>
<p title="p1Title">
  Paragraph 1
</p>
<div style="background-color:yellow">
  Div 2
</div>
<p title="p2Title" style="background-color:yellow">
  Paragraph 2
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your first line causes addition of `style` attribute to your `div1`, this line

```
$('div[title],[style]').css('border', '5px solid red');
```

and so your div1 now have `title` as well as `style` attribute both and so the next line this

```
$('[title][style]').css('background-color', 'green');
```

applies to it.

If you don't want to apply background color to your first div, just switch the order of your lines

Answer (score 2):

This line:

> ```
> $('div[title],[style]').css('border', '5px solid red');
> ```

This line takes every element with a style attribute and every div element with a title attribute and sets its inline style to have a border.

It matches the div because it has a title attribute.

Then this line:

> ```
> $('[title][style]').css('background-color', 'green');
> ```

Sets the background colour of every element with a title and a style attribute to green.

It matches the div because it started with a title attribute and the previous line added a style attribute.

Comment: perfect answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why "Div 1" got the green background color

Because your first rule, `$('div[title],[style]').css('border', '5px solid red');` says select all divs that have a title attribute and all elements with a style attibute and give them a 5px solid red border. jQuery does this by applying the CSS inline, so the divs that have the title attribute will now also have an inline style attribute.

At this point your second rule `$('[title][style]').css('background-color', 'green');` will select all elements with both a title and style attribute, which includes Div 1.

Comment: perfect answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, this is what's happening:

**1.**

```
$('div[title],[style]').css('border', '5px solid red');
```

Sets an inline style on the `div`s that don't have `style`, but have either `title` or any element that has `style`, but setting an inline style creates `style` on the `div`s without `style`.

**2.** So those `div`s with newly set `style` on them are also selected by

```
$('[title][style]').css('background-color', 'green');
```

And you see the green background color on them.

Comment: perfect answer, Thanks